# Неиспользуемые USING в файлах исходного кода

Tags: c#

В начале файла `.cs` всегда прописаны множество `using`. Часто многие из них не используются. VS делает их серыми и предлагает убрать. 
 **Вопрос:** на что повлияет удаление этих строк (конечно же только тех которые не использованны) или их можно не трогать?

Comment: Они не используются) ничего не будет если удалишь :) (те что серые)

Comment: Это повышает читаемость кода, удаление мусора скажем так. На работу по моему не как не влияют.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эти строки можно безболезненно удалять, а можно не удалять.

При компиляции эти using анализируются компилятором (см. например, Рихтер, CLR via C#, "Пространства имен и сборки": к имени класса поочереди подставляются все варианты префиксов из using'ов и выполняется поиск в подключенных через /reference сборках) и только те, которые реально используются нужны, остальные просто "вхолостую" висят. Потери времени на перебор всех вариантов префиксов настолько ничтожны, что этим легко можно пренебречь.

Я такие неиспользуемые строки обычно удаляю на автопилоте, потому что повышается читаемость кода: не нужно отвлекаться и вдумываться в ненужные строки, больше по вертикали помещается полезного кода. Тем более что у меня стоит Resharper и он предлагает их убрать, на alt+enter висит предложение. Мелочь, но на мелочах и строится хороший код: не нужно -- удали.

Но так заморачиваются не все: когда открываю чей-либо проект с гитхаба, то вижу часто, что народ не особо утруждает себя написанием чистого кода. Ну или не пользуются resharper'ом. )

PS Небольшая цитата из книги:

> Пространства имен используются для логической группировки родственных
>   типов, чтобы разработчику было проще найти нужный тип. Например, в
>   пространстве имен System.Text описаны типы для обработки строк, а в
>   пространстве имен System.IO — типы для выполнения операций
>   ввода-вывода.
>
> В следующем коде создаются объекты System.IO.FileStream и
>   System.Text.StringBuilder:
>
> ```
> public sealed class Program
> {
>     public static void Main()
>     {
>         System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(...);
>         System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Этому коду не хватает лаконичности — обращения к типам FileStream и
>   StringBuilder выглядят слишком громоздко. К счастью, многие
>   компиляторы предоставляют программистам механизмы, позволяющие
>   сократить объем набираемого текста. Например, в компиляторе C#
>   предусмотрена директива using. Следующий код аналогичен предыдущему:
>
> ```
> using System.IO;   // Подставлять префикс "System.IO"
> using System.Text; // Подставлять префикс "System.Text" 
>
> public sealed class Program
> {
>     public static void Main()
>     {
>         FileStream fs = new FileStream(...);
>         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Для компилятора пространство имен — простое средство, позволяющее
>   удлинить имя типа и сделать его уникальным за счет добавления к началу
>   имени групп символов, разделенных точками.
>
> Например, в данном примере компилятор интерпретирует FileStream как
>   System.IO.FileStream, а StringBuilder — как System.
>   Text.StringBuilder.
>
> Применять директиву using в C# не обязательно, при необходимости
>   достаточно ввести полное имя типа. Директива using заставляет
>   компилятор C# добавлять к имени указанный префикс, пока не будет
>   найдено совпадение.

Comment: `Но так заморачиваются не все: когда открываю чей-либо проект с гитхаба, то вижу часто, что народ не особо утруждает себя написанием чистого кода` когда открываешь чужой код, порой такое ощущение, что люди вообще ни о чем и никогда не заморачиваются... Счастливые )

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 умеет убирать неиспользуемые юзинги тоже, кстати.

Comment: Просто так убирать я бы не рекомендовал: если случайно убрать `System.Linq`, то потом при попытке написать LINQ-выражение Intellisense не может ничего подсказать. Вот была бы возможность некоторые юзинги прибить навсегда!