# visual studio не видит классы?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Скачал с сайта код проекта и подключил как на картинке, но visual studio не хочет  видеть классы. Что и как поправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ссылки на проект добавляются через правый клик на References (пункт меню Add Reference), там выбираете нужный проект. Открыли проект Bots в sollution explorer (обозреватель решений), правый клик на Refences (видимо, "ссылки" судя по скриншоту), потом идёте в проекты и ставите галку на проекте Web. (Или идёте в Web, оттуда подключаете Bots -- не понял что куда подключить хотите)

Comment: Нашел, все добавилось. А затененный using System так и остался не активным?

Comment: Это значит, что он не используется https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/697252/213987

Comment: Да, без них заработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ссылки на проект добавляются через правый клик на References (пункт меню Add Reference), там выбираете нужный проект.

Конкретно в вашем случае. Открыли проект Bots в Solution Explorer ("Обозреватель решений" в русской версии студии), правый клик на Refences ("ссылки"), потом идёте в Projects ("Проекты") и ставите галку на проекте Web.